# How to recover my old installed ubuntu after installing Windows

Tags: 12.04, windows, windows-7

I am using windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 dual boot system.
In my Windows 7 some issues occurred, so i re-install windows 7.
after re-installing windows 7, i lost my ubuntu os.
how can i recover my ubuntu os Help me ASAP

Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: Google for or search here for "Restore Grub Dual Boot"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot-Repair is a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues you may encounter in Ubuntu like when you can't boot Ubuntu after installing Windows or another Linux distribution, or when you can't boot Windows after installing Ubuntu, or when GRUB is not displayed anymore, some upgrade breaks GRUB, etc.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair